# How to use nodemailer within new Google policy?

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

Well, it's quite simple actually... I'm trying to use nodemailer but everytime a try to call the mailer fucntion, it returns an auth error. I searched the error and apparently it's cause because of Google "**less secure apps access**" (*https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps*) option, it has to be enabled, but the problem is: since may 30th of 2022, Google updated it's policy, and no longer has this option, so i can't use nodemailer in gmail anymore?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4EK5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TCAv.png)

I tried to search the problem and find how to enable the "**access to less secure apps**" on Google gmail account configuration, but since Google updated it's policy, and they removed that option, i can't find any other solution. I didn't find anyone else with this problem either.

Answer (score 0):

if you enabled 2fa on your google account you can create an apps password.

you can then use the apps password in place of your actual Gmail password in your Code

[how to create an apps password](https://youtu.be/Y_u5KIeXiVI)